# Strange iterpritation coffeescript to javascript. Why?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm performing get request in coffee script:

```
parseRequest = (line) ->
     try
       request = JSON.parse(line)
     catch err
     try
    switch request.method
        when 'authorize'
            req = http.get { port: 8080, path: "/test/config" }, (res) ->
            console.log "Get response: #{res.statusCode}"
            res.on 'data', (chunk) -> 
                console.log('body: ' + chunk)
                request.params[0] = JSON.parse(chunk).config.username
                console.log "Request: " + request.params[0]
                request.params[1] = JSON.parse(chunk).config.password
                console.log "Request: " + request.params[1]
                line = JSON.stringify(request)
                console.log "Changed username and pass to: #{request.params[0]},#{request.params[1]}"
                ......{lot of code}.........
                return line
```

In output I get this:

```
 Changed username and pass to: original,p
 Get response: 200
 body: {"config":{"username":"newuser","password":"newpass"}}
 Request: newuser
 Request: newpass
```

So last log message output first and in result of function, that is store in 'line', still contains old values. Of course, I try a lot of different variants, in attempts to fix this problem, but get no luck. Then I decide to look at compiled javascript based on this coffee script. I see this:

```
req = http.get({
    port: 8080,
    path: "/test/config"
}, function(res) {
    console.log("Get response: " + res.statusCode);
    return res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log('body: ' + chunk);
        request.params[0] = JSON.parse(chunk).config.username;
        console.log("Request: " + request.params[0]);
        request.params[1] = JSON.parse(chunk).config.password;
        return console.log("Request: " + request.params[1]);
     });
 });
 line = JSON.stringify(request);
 console.log("Changed username and pass to: " + request.params[0] + "," + request.params[1]);
```

In java script last two lines, was moved out of scope function on('data'), that's why I recive last output in first line, and that's why variable line contains old values. But why coffee script translate my script to such javascript code? Something connected with visibility of variable line? How can I fix it and get what I excpected in coffeescript?

Comment: Could it be an issue with whitespace?

Comment: Is that the real indentation in your `parseRequest`? If it is, it is very strange and strange indentation is a really bad idea in CoffeeScript (or any other language where whitespace defines the structure). Perhaps you're mixing spaces and tabs. BTW, just because you can use anonymous functions doesn't mean you should, That *lot of code* suggests that you might want to refactor your code into a bunch of smaller named functions for clarity.

Comment: Do you mean indentation of whole parseRequest function or only about its first line? Of course I have reformate code on stackoverflow, but idea of indentations still the same. I will check possible issue with mixing of whitepspaces and tabs. Coffee script preferm tabs, as I understand?

Comment: Spaces are more common in whitespace-sensitive languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in mixing spaces and tabs. All lines that should be in function has 6 tabs equal indentation, but in all strings that was include in function, there were 4 spaces between 3rd and 5th tab, so it looks like tab, but was not so. Meanwhile two last strings have only tabs in indentation. That was a problem of coping some string from other source.